# Laravel 5 package router.php being ignored

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have followed the Laravel documentation regarding service providers and I am trying to create my own package/module.

My router.php file for my package is being totally ignored, but I can dd() from with the boot and register functions fine:

```
abstract class ServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot()
    {
        if ($module = $this->getModule(func_get_args())) {
            include __DIR__.'/'.$module.'/routes.php';
        }
        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/'.$module.'/Views', 'core');
    }

    public function register()
    {
        if ($module = $this->getModule(func_get_args())) {

        }
    }

    public function getModule($args)
    {
        $module = (isset($args[0]) and is_string($args[0])) ? $args[0] : null;

        return $module;
    }

}
```

And in my app/Modules/Core/router.php:

```
Route::get('/test', function(){
    return 'hello';
});
```

I simply get a page not found error (not a Laravel error).

What am I missing?

Comment: Well if it's not a Laravel not found error it does have nothing to do with your route. Do you have an `test` directory inside `public` ?

Comment: And other routes work like normal?

Comment: @lukasgeiter It seems nothing works except for the '/' route, the default /home route gives the same error: The requested URL /home was not found on this server.

Comment: This sounds a lot like an `.htaccess` problem. Try `/index.php/home`

Comment: @lukasgeiter That worked, weird. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Check if your `public/.htaccess` is [correct](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess) and make sure mod_rewrite and `.htaccess` (`AllowOverride On`) are enabled.

Comment: @ChrisForrence route:cache causes a LogicException

Comment: @lukasgeiter FacepalmException...Reinstalled my wamp and forget to reenable mod_rewrite =/ thanks! Now all is working :D

Comment: Haha no problem. What do we now do with this question? Should I write an answer or do you want to delete it?

Comment: Make your comment your answer if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on what you said here

> I simply get a page not found error (not a Laravel error).

It sounds like you don't have your web server setup correctly.  i.e. This error is happening a level above (or below, depending on your point of view) Laravel.

Try loading a route from

```
http://example.com/index.php/home
```

You'll probably find Laravel responds just fine to that page.

PHP framework like Laravel usually direct all traffic to a single `index.php` -- sometimes this file is called a front controller, other times a front loader, still other times an index bootstrapper. It has countless names. By directing all traffic to this one file, the framework can implement its own controller dispatching logic.

If you're seeing a *web server* error page and not a Laravel web page, that probably means

1. You're missing the `.htaccess` file in `public/`
2. Your web server is configured to ignore `.htaccess` files
3. Your web server doesn't have the `MOD_REWRITE` module installed or enabled
4. Some combination of the above

The `MOD_REWRITE` module is the apache module that allows an `.htaccess` file to say

> Hey, all you requests -- don't server a file, go to `index.php` instead.

Other web servers (like nginx) have a different module for the same purpose.  Consult your documentation if that's you.